# how to train for sit and reach?

Tags: training, stretching, core, lower-back

One of my physical fitness test is called sit and reach.

What are the best methods to train for this "exercise"?

Yes, I do agree that it requires flexibility. However, I heard of different methods from friends on the use of correct muscles.

Some says it uses abs, while others says it's the back or the legs!

Is there a proper method?
What should I look at when I'm doing sit and reach?

Comment: Do you have additional information about what this test includes?

Comment: This q/a on how to [stretch hamstrings](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/576/how-can-i-stretch-hamstrings-in-isolation/3940#3940) will give you good hamstring stretches.  However, as pointed out you need to also stretch your [gastroc muscles](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/4192/reducing-tightness-in-calf-and-soleus/5667#5667), glutes, adductors and back muscles.  Even loosening up your upper back and shoulders can help you gain a bit more reach.

Answer (score 3):

The sit and reach test is part of a general health assessment battery of tests. The basic method is to sit on the floor, legs flat, with feet against a box or other vertical stop. A measuring stick or device is used to see how far a person can reach towards (or past) their toes. It's used as a measure of general health when included in a full assessment. Poor results are an indicator that the person may be predisposed towards lower back pain and/or injury unless corrected.

The main limiters for this test are going to be your hamstrings, your lower back (erector spinae), and possibly to some extent the gluteal muscles.

While somewhat self serving, [this answer](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/13597/flexibility-training-for-taekwondo) covers all (And then some) of the stretches that will help with this (There are many many other stretches, these are the main ones. Every stretch/muscle group will have multiple variants). The particular ones that you want to do for this specific test would be 1, 2, 4, 7 and 8.