# Stiff calf after 20 minutes of cycling

Tags: calf, stiffness

My doctor has recommended cycling to heal from a leg injury.

I think it is working, but, unfortunately, another problem is arising.

My right leg was injured (in the Adductor) and I seem to compensate it by making more effort with the left leg. I end up with a stiff calf after 20 minutes of heavy-ish cycling. To avoid a new injury, I have to wait a couple of days before going back to the gym.

How can I reduce this stiffness ? Should I drink more liquids ? Eat bananas ? (they are cheap here, I am from Brazil. And I remember hearing something about cramps and bananas) Do some sort of warm up exercise ? (which ?)

Comment: The calf is made up of the gastrocnemius and soleus muscles.  This [q/a about stretching the calf](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/15942/how-to-ease-tight-soleus/17979#17979) has info that should get you started until you get a full answer to your question.  You also need to consider your form.

Comment: @BackInShapeBuddy And the stretching should be done right before the cycling ?

Comment: "Dynamic stretching" can be done before exercise, but "static stretching" should be done after the tissue is warmed up.  See #5. ["When to stretch" in this answer](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/2940/daily-stretch-routine-to-increase-flexibilty-and-overall-fitness/2941#2941).  Here is some info on [dynamic stretching](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/8262/dynamic-stretching-as-warm-up/8308#8308).

Comment: The obvious answer is "stop with the heavyish cycling", and make it much lighter. That will give your body a better chance to adapter. I would also make sure you are using your bike's gearing so that you don't have to push too hard.

Comment: Gradually increase efforts, instead of just jumping into "heavyish" cycling. Also, seat position and pedaling technique can impact calf activation a lot.